# $.ajax using async:false cant use timeout:5000, how to use both together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: c.cls.server,
   data: {
     mode: 'Perspective',
     id: c.uid,
     points: points,
     width: c.cls.canvasMaxWidth,
     caseid: caseid,
     imgtype: imgtype
   },
   async: false,
   timeout: 5000,
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   success: function(e) {
     result = e;
   },
   error: function(r, s, e) {
     c.onError(status + e);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Never, ever use `async: false`. I feel like a broken record saying this all the God damn time.

Comment: If you can show us more of your code, specifically how you use the `result` variable, we can show give you an asynchronous solution using callbacks.

Comment: _"how to use both together?"_ You can't, and even if you could, you shouldn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`. Try this:

```js
var xhr = '';
xhr = $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: c.cls.server,
   data: {
     mode: 'Perspective',
     id: c.uid,
     points: points,
     width: c.cls.canvasMaxWidth,
     caseid: caseid,
     imgtype: imgtype
   },
   async: false,   
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   beforeSend: function(e){

      setTimeout(function(){ 
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4) xhr.abort();
      },5000);

   },success: function(e) {
     result = e;
   },
   error: function(r, s, e) {
     c.onError(status + e);
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to add  new method, if timeout alert a  message and abort session

Comment: The `setTimeout` callback would be blocked until the request finished. This isn't a solution to OP's problem.